# Finding the average cost of producing an item when given a number of items and an equation

Tags: calculus

Suppose that the dollar cost of producing $x$ radios is $c(x)=400+20x-0.2x^2$.

Find the average cost per radio of producing the first $45$ radios.

A. $\$895.00$

B. $\$845.00$

C. $\$19.89$

D. $\$495.00$

For this question I just plugged in $45$ for $ x$ and then solved and got A. $\$895$ as my answer. My question is if I did this correctly and if not what other way I could go about approaching this question to answer it correctly.

Comment: You then need to divide by $45$, since they want the average cost **per radio**.

Comment: Oh okay thank you for helping me catch that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $c(x)=400+20x-0.2x^2$ gives the cost of producing $x$ radios. So plugging in $45$ only gives you the cost of producing $45$ radios.

The average cost **per radio** is thus given by:

$$\frac{c(45)}{45}=\frac{400+20(45)-0.2(45)^2}{45}\approx 19.89.$$

So the answer is C: $\$ 19.89$.